# Calculating GPS coordinates given distance between points

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, interpolation

I have 2 points where I know the GPS coordinates of one of the points. Additionally, I know their coordinates in some reference frame where I can calculate the distance between them in real world units (like meters).

So, the setup could be as follows

```
Point A: (GPS coordinates), (x1, y1)
Point B: (x2, y2)
```

where the simple Euclidean distance between A and B gives the distance between them in meters. For this, we assume that these points are fairly localized (spatially very close) and they both lie on the same plane.

Given this setup, could we calculate the GPS coordinate of point B?

Comment: The formal name for solving a second point from a point, bearing, and distance is the [Direct (aka Forward) Problem of Geodesy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems). Most GIS software is capable of this; you just need to choose one. You will also need to determine the angle, since without it, you are defining a spheroidal circle.

Comment: Oh awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @Vince One quick question. The points I have are very close together and my model assumption is that the points lie on the same plane. In that case, can I set the angle to 0?

Comment: An angle of zero gets a northward orientation. Generally no, it is not safe to assume zero.